# How to enforce a 2.0-capable processor in an XSLT?

Tags: xslt-2.0

Using `XSLT 2.0`, how can I check in my stylesheet that an *actual* `XSLT 2.0` capable processor is being used?

`system-property()`, a 2.0 function, still returns 2.0 on ones that it cannot support it properly.

Comment: That is what the `version` attribute of your `stylesheet` root element is for. :) Set `version="2.0"` to request XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Yes, I do set it. However when someone uses a non-2.0 capable processor, like Xalan or Saxon 6.5, they still run - and report 2.0 as the version - and fail to do their job with a mess of errors!

Comment: The result of system-property('xsl:version') should be 1.0 for an XSLT 1.0 processor; but there could perhaps be exceptions especially if the processor has implemented one or two 2.0 features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/processorTest2.xml with Saxon 6.5.5 or with Firefox or with Chrome or with Opera or with IE 10 they all report the `xsl:version` as `1` or `1.0`, none of them reports `2.0`. I have not tried Xalan however.

Comment: Weird :( oXygen was reporting 2.0. I'll recheck again.

Comment: I've tried running your xsl after having added ```<xsl:value-of>ANY</xsl:value-of>``` into it, which is one of the errors that is tripping up Saxon 6.5.5. It raises a complication error, so I guess it fails before it gets to running the stylesheet - and I don't think there's a way to prevent that, is there?

Comment: There is some specification of forwards compatible processing in http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#forwards. Whether that helps to avoid compilation errors when an XSLT 1.0 processor encounters an `xsl:value-of` element with no `select` attribute but some child contents I am not sure, admittedly that is an area I am not familiar with.